# How to web scrape all the text after href by specific class in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to web scrape some information from a top music list on a online website:
https://moov.hk/#/chart/PC1000000014.
I would like to scrape all the artists name, songs and the ranking. However, I have some troubles to select the information that I want.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

page = requests.get('https://moov.hk/#/chart/PC1000000014')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
for div in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'artist'}):
    print(div.find('a')['href'])
    print(div.find('a').contents[0])
```

and the error output:

```
line 9, in <module>
    print(div.find('a')['href'])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

How to find all the information that I mentioned above and store them by using Dataframe?

Expected output:

```
Ranking        Artist          Song
1              MC 張天賦        世一
2              Ian 陳卓賢       再見 寧靜海
3              Edan 呂爵安      LOVERSE
4....
...
```

Comment: *Always and first of all, take a look at your soup to see if all the expected ingredients are in place.* What do you find in your `soup`?

Answer (score 0):

Content is rendered dynamically and comes from an additional source, so you have to fetch the data from there - For more check your browsers dev tool network section under the xhr tab.

Use [`pandas.json_normalize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) to read the JSON into a `dataframe` that could be sliced to your needs:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

pd.json_normalize(requests.get('https://mtg.now.com/moov/api/profile/getProfile?refType=PC&profileId=PC1000000014&deviceType=web&_=1676918519102').json(), ['dataObject',['modules'][0],['chartItems']])
```

##### Output

|  | ranking | previousRanking | viewCount | albumId | albumTitle | artistId | artist | productId | explicit | productType | productLength | thumbnail | refType | qualities | vipLevel | previousViewCount | productTitle | artists |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 3625 | VAWM01413371A | This is MC | 01241603 | MC 張天賦 | VAWM09323421 | 0 | AUDIO | 264 | https://images.sysapi.mtg.now.com/mposter/album/l/VAWM01413371A_l.jpg | ADO | HD,LL,HR | 1 | 4262 | 世一 | [{'name': 'MC 張天賦', 'refId': '01241603'}] |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 3489 | VAMN01412659A | 再見 寧靜海 | 00568220 | 陳卓賢 Ian | VAMN09320718 | 0 | AUDIO | 251 | https://images.sysapi.mtg.now.com/mposter/album/l/VAMN01412659A_l.jpg | ADO | HD,LL,HR | 0 | 4082 | 再見 寧靜海 | [{'name': '陳卓賢 Ian', 'refId': '00568220'}] |
| 2 | 3 | 3 | 2799 | VAMN01395396A | LOVERSE | 01330214 | Edan 呂爵安 | VAMN09261620 | 0 | AUDIO | 266 | https://images.sysapi.mtg.now.com/mposter/album/l/VAMN01395396A_l.jpg | ADO | HD,LL,HR | 0 | 3224 | LOVERSE | [{'name': 'Edan 呂爵安', 'refId': '01330214'}] |
| 3 | 4 | 4 | 2295 | VAID01391653A | 第一個迷 | 01864588 | Jeffrey 魏浚笙 | VAID09250478 | 0 | AUDIO | 248 | https://images.sysapi.mtg.now.com/mposter/album/l/VAID01391653A_l.jpg | ADO | HD,LL | 0 | 2709 | 第一個迷 | [{'name': 'Jeffrey 魏浚笙', 'refId': '01864588'}] |

...

Answer (score 0):

The page gets the data from moov's API, you can use dev tools on the browser to get the endpoint, for the ranking you linked it's : `https://mtg.now.com/moov/api/profile/getProfile?refType=PC&profileId=PC1000000014&deviceType=web`.
You can change the `profileId` paramater to get the data from the other rankings.

I can suggest using [Scrapy](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) to deal with this, here is the code to get the list into a DataFrame:

```
import json
import scrapy
import pandas as pd


class MusicRankingSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "music"

    def start_requests(self):
        ranking_id = "PC1000000007"
        url = f"https://mtg.now.com/moov/api/profile/getProfile?refType=PC&profileId={ranking_id}&deviceType=web"
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        music_data = json.loads(response.text)
        music_list = music_data["dataObject"]["modules"][0]["chartItems"]

        ranking = [
            {
                "ranking": item["ranking"],
                "artist": item["artist"],
                "title": item["productTitle"],
            }
            for item in music_list
        ]
        s = pd.DataFrame(ranking)
        print(s)
```

Also, if you don't want to deal with running the spider manually you can use [estela](https://github.com/bitmakerla/estela) which is a spider management solution developed by [Bitmaker](https://bitmaker.la/en/).